# Why can't my textarea be disabled and have an id

Tags: html

I've got a textarea that I want disabled so the client can't edit anything within it. However it doesn't work except for when I remove it's id. The only thing I'm using the id for is to insert text into it with javascript.

Here is the textarea:

```
<textarea id="partnerTextArea" class="textarea" disabled readonly ></textarea>
```

When I remove the id tag, it becomes disabled, but when it's there it isn't disabled.

Is there something wrong with what i've done. Do I need to provide any more information for the solution to this? In my Js file, all i'm doing is getting the textarea by it's id and setting it's value.

Any reason why the id is preventing it from being disabled?

Comment: We can't help you without a proper [mcve].

Comment: Any css being applied on `#partnerTextArea` or `.textarea` or just `textarea`?

Answer (score 1):

Fix your html and it will work (attributes go inside the opening tag, not between the opening and closing tags).

Your `<textarea>` is not disabled because you haven't given it an attribute of disabled.

```html
<textarea id="partnerTextArea" class="textarea" disabled readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: That has the exact same results

Comment: I edited my post, I pasted my code incorrectly, sorry. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Please add your javascript to the question